# Как использовать .lib файлы при создании библиотек?

Tags: c, библиотеки, lib

Вопрос в следующем: у меня есть библиотека с уже готовым кодом, как теперь мою библиотеку перенести в *.lib файл, и вообще есть ли смысл использовать статические библиотеки, если да то как добавить такой *.lib файл в объектный код?
И ещё один маленький вопрос, как правильно компилировать *.lib?

Answer (score 0):

> есть ли смысл использовать статические библиотеки ?

Я думаю, что если бы смысла не было, то их никто бы и не использовал.

> как добавить такой *.lib файл в код?

Это невозможно. В библиотеках находится **объектный** код, а в Ваших файлах - **исходный** код. Эти две вещи не смешиваются. Но библиотеки можно добавить на этапе линковки.

> как правильно компилировать *.lib?

Это зависит от:

1. Операционной системы, в которой Вы работатете;
2. Компилятора, который Вы используете;
3. Сборщика, который управляет работой компилятора.

Comment: Хорошо, я немного перефразирую вопрос, как добавить статическую библиотеку в объектный код на этапе линковки?

Comment: @Centrix Прошу ещё раз уточнить пункты 1. - 3. из моего ответа. Если речь идёт о 1:Linux, 2:gcc, 3:Без ничего, то ответ очень простой: добавьте Ваш файл статической библиотеки my_lib.a в комндную строку вызова компилятора. Напрмер так: *gcc -o test my_lib.a main.c*. Здесь очень существенен **порядок** указания модулей в командной строке. Те, которые **используются** должны стоять перед теми, которые **используют**

Answer (score 0):

Если есть dll файл, можно из него сгенерить lib файл с помощью утилиты buildlib из состава компилятора lcc (for windows): buildlib.exe   []
input list - тесктовый файл с именами функций из dll (узнаются через утилиту dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS ...), например avifil32.exp:
AVIFIL32.DLL
_AVIBuildFilter@12
_AVIBuildFilterA@12
_AVIBuildFilterW@12
_AVIClearClipboard@0
...
_AVISave
...
символ @ нужен для функций STDAPI, @12 - размер стека переменных (3х4 байт)
@0 - функция STDAPI (void)
lib file - имя создаваемой lib
Потом lib file можно использовать при линковке компилятором.